# SOQL Injection Solutions Help - (Used esacapeSingleQuotes(str) - gives error = no viable alternative at character '\' )

Tags: apex, soql, soql-injection

I am facing some issues with following SOQL Query : 
My Scanner result gave me SOQL Injection Errors, can anyone help in fixing those -

I am going throw lots of Google Search and Stuff, but it will be great if I am able to fix these ASAP.

1)

```
 String query = 'SELECT Id,Subject,Status,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Owner.IsActive,ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE OwnerId in (SELECT ID FROM User WHERE isActive = true) AND ActivityDate ='+ selected;
```

2)

```
myuserid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userid');
        filter =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Filter');
 squery = 'SELECT Id,Subject,Status,OwnerId,Owner.Name,Owner.IsActive,Priority,ActivityDate,ReminderDateTime,Whoid,Who.name FROM Task WHERE OwnerId=\'' + myuserid + 
                        '\' AND ActivityDate='+filter;                        

List<Task> lsttask = Database.Query**(String.escapeSingleQuotes(squery));**
```

**ERROR :**

> System.QueryException: line 1:137 no viable alternative at character
>   '\'

Comment: What scanner is this, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: SOQL/SOQL  Injection - Apex force.com Critical  Security Risk

Comment: You are taking a URL parameter and sticking it directly into your SOQL statement without escaping it. Imagine a `Filter` parameter like ":internalClassVariable ALL ROWS". If someone were trying to mess up your query, it would be pretty easy.

Comment: Will use of escapeSingleQuotes will solve my whole problem ??

Comment: Rather than escaping the entire query, try escaping just the variables "myuserid" and "filter" and then using bind syntax :variable to put them into the query string.

Answer (score 3):

The salesforce security scanner should of give you some potential mitigation information such as:

> To prevent a SOQL injection attack, avoid using dynamic SOQL queries.
>   Instead, use static queries and binding variables. The Mitigations
>   vulnerable example above could be re-written using static SOQL as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> public class SOQLController { public String name {
>     get { return name;}
>     set { name = value;} }
>     public PageReference query() {
>         String queryName = '%' + name + '%'
>         queryResult = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE (IsDeleted = false and Name like :queryName)]; return null;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you must use dynamic SOQL, use the `escapeSingleQuotes` method to
>   sanitize user-supplied input. This method adds the escape character
>   () to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a
>   user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated
>   as enclosing strings, instead of database commands

You can use the `escapeSingleQuotes` method in the following way:

```
Database.Query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(squery));
```

More information on escapeSingleQuotes can be found [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_escapeSingleQuotes)

Comment: Yes I have got above example in Scanner report, but I am trying to add variable names as shown here (in Section - "Dynamic SOQL Considerations  " 3rd query) ---- 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

which shouldn't have to give any problems.

Comment: Will use of  escapeSingleQuotes  will solve my whole problem ??

Comment: It should solve all the dynamic SOQL issues.

Comment: I updated my code with escapeSingleQuotes which cause another error while loading VF page - Updated Questions with error and code updates

Answer (score 0):

Use String.escapeSingleQuotes(String) method and then use variables such as myuserid, filter etc. in SOQL